# Select * from Table A (variable) issues

Tags: db2

Recently I'm reading some DB2 code. But I don't know what's the function of these brackets in the "from" part.

```
 SELECT
   A INTO      TypeCd
   FROM        TX
   WHERE        TOKEN_ID IN (SELECT ELEMENTS
   FROM  (AB_OWN.ELEMENTS (pv_token_id)) AS T) LIMIT 1;
```

In the above code, pv_token_id is a variable.

I mean I know the formation of select query is like : 
Select * from Table A

But I don't know what this formation means: 
Select * from Table A(variable)

what do the brackets and variable do in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a table function use, but with omitted *TABLE* keyword.
It should be like below:

```
SELECT ELEMENTS
FROM  TABLE (AB_OWN.ELEMENTS (pv_token_id)) AS T
```

Look at the *table-function-reference* description of the [table-reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059206.html), which you can use in the [from-clause](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059205.html) of [subselect](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000875.html).
*pv_token_id* here is a variable passed to the function as a parameter.
Consider a table function use in *SELECT* as use of ordinary table. It's the convenient way to get a result set for further processing (joining with other tables/table functions, filtering, ect.).